# Where can I start with programmable Hardware?

Tags: c++, c, embedded, hardware, usb

I've had a desire to learn at least a tiny bit about programming hardware for quite some time now and thought I'd ask here to get some starting points.  I am a reasonably accomplished programmer with Delphi and Objective-c experience but have never even listened to a device port / interupt (I dont even know the terminology) let alone programmed a piece of hardware.

To start with what I would like to be able to do is,

- Buy a simple bit of kit with 2,3 or 10 buttons
- Plug the device into  my pc via USB
- Listen to the device and write some code to do something once the button is pressed.

I reckon this is a good place to start, anyone got pointers on hardware to buy or how I could start this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I like the [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/), easy to use, open source and a great community!

Good to get started with, and uses a subset of C/C++.

Also, has alot of addon hardware available, like GPS, Bluetooth, Wifi etc

My experiences with Arduino have been nothing but good, from the point you get it out of it's box (and install the free compiler on either Windows / Mac / Linux), to building your first 'sketch' (a project or application for the Arduino).

Making an application is easy, you have a `Setup` Method, which is called on startup, and then a `loop` method which is looped while the Arduino is running.

Then all you have to do is hook either inputs or outputs up to the pins on the Arduino board, tell the code what they are and hopefully you'll get the desired output.

One other really good thing about the Arduino (and others I'm sure) is that you now have a use for those old broken printers, or 2x CD-Rom's that no one wants, and every other little bit of out dated technology. It's amazing what you can find in a server room!

Now, I have only worked on small projects, like plugging in an LCD, and reading the room temp and various projects like that. But based on what I have done, I am happy with the Ardunio, it gives a good base to embedded programming and if it's not enough, you can always go bigger!

My 2 cents!

Comment: Arduino even comes with a demo app where you can read which input pins are on over the USB link (acting as a serial port)

Comment: Yes, it is pretty awesome, and full of features. Pretty much just held back by your imagination. It's like playing wiht lego, except for a grown up :) IMO

Answer (score 3):

There's also the hot-off-the press [netduino](http://www.netduino.com/) which uses the .NET Micro Framework and Microsoft Visual C# Express. I don't know that's it's better than the Arduino but it's another option.

Comment: Cool, but I have a bone to pick with the person who wrote the script for the introductory video: if I'm looking to program on hardware, I probably already know what a `while` loop does.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you start with AVR programming for microprocessors. Yeh it might be a bit too low level. but I know many people that have started with it for hardware programming. you could find a compiler here. http://winavr.sourceforge.net/  and a good tutorial here: http://www.ladyada.net/learn/avr/

Answer (score 2):

The previous poster mentioned the Arduino, but you should also consider a [Teensy](http://www.pjrc.com/teensy/). It's basically the same thing, but price is a little better. You also have the option of using it in "Arduino" mode, or raw AVR mode. I don't know if Arduinos give you both options.

There is a [comparison page](http://www.pjrc.com/teensy/teensyduino.html) where you can see the Teensy has some better hardware. The built-in USB gives it much better performance.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely suggest trying out various microcontrollers.  [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/) Controllers are nice and have a [number](http://www.ladyada.net/learn/arduino/) [of](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/HomePage) [tutorials](http://www.arduinotutorials.com/).

However, its not your only option.  In school, I worked with [Microchip PICs](http://www.microchip.com/), which are also quite nice for the hobbyist scene.  The nice thing about the PIC was that our microcontrollers textbook supported it, so we got to see the application as we were learning the theory.

Comment: I would recommend using a PIC18F4550 or newer.  You can request free samples--up to 5 of them a month. Don't tell Microchip but I have lots of these stocked up from requesting samples over the years.  The n there's the PICkit2 kit (no free samples for this guy but still cheap) which lets you program your chip via USB.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right, you are not interested in embedded programming. You want to buy something that works from the begining and control it from Windows.

When it comes to buttons, there is not much to do in Windows. These are HID controls and Windows handles all the interfacing for you. Nothing too exciting there.

In that case you can grab any Joystick and use the DirectInput (a part of the DirectX tech.) to interact with it. With force feedback you can do some cool stuff.

A more fun project would be to buy a Wii control and write some fun applicartions.
Look at this site to get some ideas of what I mean:

http://johnnylee.net/projects/wii/

Since Windows has no support for a Wii contrller, you really get to do some work here :)

Answer (score 1):

I see that you like Delphi, so you can take a look at AvrCo Multitasking Pascal for AVR. You can try it at http://www.e-lab.de. MEGA8/88 version is free. There are tons of drivers, simulator,  JTAG online debugger and programmer with visualization of all standard devices (for a startup, you can make a simple LPT programmer with just a few resistors). It can also make programs for all Arduino devices out there, since AVR is in their hearth. Atmel's STK500 is a good beginner board, with leds, switches, and few other peripherals. If you prefer open source, then WinAVR with GCC could be your path.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, Arduino is a good choice. The community is large and helpful. The nice thing is that you can transition right to a "real" language by using the GCC port for AVR micros, if you want. On my latest project I did this - prototype most of it with Arduino, then re-write it in C.

Starting with buttons and LEDs is a great idea. Build some confidence in working with basic hardware first, before modding the Wii!

Some links:

- Windows GCC cross compiler (1 step install) for AVR: [WinAVR](http://winavr.sourceforge.net/)
- A Arduino clone kit
- [Adafruit](http://www.adafruit.com/) is another good source of starter hardware and tech advice
- The embedded [StackOverflow](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Any program you already write interacts with hardware, there's the monitor, keyboard, mouse, speaker etc.  Getting a simple setup where your program can deal with buttons on a USB device will not teach you that much about working with hardware.  It's partly a question of how low you want to go in the software stack and how much you want to learn about what happens at the point where the software ends.

1. Get yourself a copy of "The Art of
   Electronics". It's a **relatively** easy read and covers everything between Ohm's law and the microprocessor and will give you a good idea of what the complete system does.
2. Read it.
3. Check out Digikey.  You can buy anything hardware related from resistors, capacitors, IC's, low cost boards easily online and for reasonable prices.

Other replies mentioned Microchip PIC and Atmel AVR which are small and simple microcontrollers.  Both companies have a wealth of application notes, check out their web site, read through some app notes.  You can get low cost evaluation boards for the above or something like the Arduino mentioned in other replies.  Consider designing and building your own board to force yourself to learn the basics.  Find a friend who is an EE or serious hobbyist who wouldn't mind helping you with some tips.

If you want to learn more about PC hardware you can take a look at some simple device drivers (e.g. printer or serial port) under Windows (download the WinDDK), Linux or even DOS.  Programming under something like DOS on a PC allows for relatively easy interaction with the PC hardware, you can use a printer port to read push buttons etc.

Links (I'm a new user so I can't link directly):

www.amazon.com/Art-Electronics-Paul-Horowitz/dp/0521370957

www.digikey.com/

www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=2879

www.atmel.com/products/avr/